# VSCode is not recognizing imports when in a virtual environment, and does not recognize an attribute for a module that I know exists?

Tags: python, virtualenv, wrapper

I opened up this file after a while of not using it, switched to the virtual environment - and now some of my imports are not seeming to function correctly. In an api wrapper called python-fmrest (not fmrest)it is not recognizing the attribute Server, to be specific.

I have reimported every module using pip, am using the current version of python3 as well. This used to work in the past but I am not sure what the issue is now - could be that I have created a new venv but I don't understand the issue if everything is imported.

```
import fmrest

fms = fmrest.Server('https://filemaker.mann.com',
                    user='fmserver',
                    password='1234',
                    database='testVignesh',
                    layout='testVignesh',
                    verify_ssl=True)
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
File "server.py", line 19, in <module>
    fms = fmrest.Server('https://filemaker.mann.com',
AttributeError: module 'fmrest' has no attribute 'Server'
```

Comment: I have changed the settings.json in vscode to be using the virtual environment as well.

Comment: One thought that comes to mind, have you got a file called `fmrest.py`? It could be sourcing that instead of the actual module